# What's the best way to send emails from a web server to miminise bouces-backs and spam blocks?

Tags: smtp, email-spam

I've got a web server that sends email (from IIS 5.1) to clients throughout the world. I have found that sometimes emails get bounced on valid addresses, or they never arrive, or get treated as spam.

I'm considering using am external SMTP service.

Will this help? Are there other ways/tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a properly maintained SMTP service[1] might[2] avoid many problems when dealing with spam filters.

For more specific help you'll have to describe specific error messages, post example mails with headers and bounce messages. And, you should do so on http://serverfault.com, which is the better community for such questions.

[1] i.e. one which has proper DNS records, doesn't do ratware stuff, creates appropriate headers and is not on any DUL or RBLs.

[2] of course, it doesn't help if you're triggering content based filters.